# MySQL Connector: ‘MySQL_Driver’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql’

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to reproduce an [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html) for C++ MySQL Connector library in Ubuntu 16.04. `libmysqlcppconn-dev` is installed. Here is my program:

```
  #include <mysql_connection.h>
  #include <cppconn/driver.h>
  #include <cppconn/exception.h>
  #include <cppconn/resultset.h>
  #include <cppconn/statement.h>
  #include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

  int main(void)
  {
      sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
      sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection* con;
      delete party;
      driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
      con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
      return 0;
  }
```

I'm trying to compile it:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/cppconn probe.cpp -lmysqlcppconn
```

Compiling gives an error:

```
probe.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
probe.cpp:31:5: error: ‘MySQL_Driver’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql’
     sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
     ^
probe.cpp:31:31: error: ‘driver’ was not declared in this scope
     sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
                           ^
probe.cpp:34:14: error: ‘get_mysql_driver_instance’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql’
     driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
```

YouCompleteMe offers various members of `sql::mysql::*` but also no `MySQL_Driver`.

What is wrong here? Maybe I should install some header files, or use other compiler options? Sorry if my question is simple or stupid.

Comment: `#include <mysql_driver.h>`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thank you. There is no `mysql_driver.h` in examples for some reason.